# Android Studio - Admob error - China

Tags: android-studio, admob, vpn, great-firewall-of-china

I am trying to add admob to my app, following the instructions

added to the build.gradle (project) section maven

```
   allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

}

added to build.gradle (app) section for play service

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

}

In mainactivity

import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    // Sample AdMob app ID:
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "MY_ADMOB_APP");
```

When try to sync project get error message

FAILED TO SYNC : COM.GOOGLE.ANDROID.GMS:PLAY-SERVICE-ADS:11.8.0

I am in China so using a VPN, is this causing the issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not using a VPN and check if Gradle is in offline mode

Comment: Great worked when VPN stopped and gradle in offline mode